# Help me choose a linear algebra book

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

As an undergrad, I studied linear algebra from Hoffman and Kunze. It was a good book and it covers some of the stuff I care about, but I'm wondering if there are better resources. The topics I would like to revisit (and primarily from a matrix pov) are matrix decompositions, normal forms, spectral theorems, variational characterization of eigenvalues, and some special well behaved matrices (graph matrices/doubly stochastic matrices). Different resources seem to address different topics really well, and I've picked some stuff up from Bhatia, Trefethan-Bau, Spielman's notes on spectral graph theory, but are there books that address all/most of these topics? There's a few books I came across, which I list below, but I would be glad to hear more suggestions (hopefully with some detail so that it becomes easier to pick a book).

1. Advanced Linear Algebra: S Roman (greatest overlap so far, but
   possibly not very matrix centric)
2. Advanced Linear and Matrix
   Algebra: Nathaniel Johnston (this came out earlier this month)
3. Linear Algebra and Optimization for Machine Learning: Charu Aggarwal
   (my interest is not from an ML point of view, so apprehensive that
   this might go down a different path)

Comment: Check out Matrix Computations by Golub & Van Loan

Comment: @Boshu One reference that covers everything on your list is *Matrix Analysis* by Horn and Johnson.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @BenGrossmann and xX AC E Xx Do these talk about graph/stochastic matrices? I have flipped through Horn/Johnson but don't recall seeing that. Then again not many resources as good as Spielman's Spectral Graph Theory notes.

Comment: @Boshu Most of what they cover has to do with positive matrices more generally (e.g. the Frobenius theorem) but I thought that they cover Birkhoff’s theorem for doubly stochastic matrices as well; I might be getting books mixed in my head